# redirect to created object after form submission

Tags: django

Goal: To redirect to the 'build log' after the form is submitted

view:

```
@login_required
def buildLogCreate(request,  pk):

    post = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
   
    if request.user.id != post.author_id:
        raise PermissionDenied()

    currentUser = request.user
    form = BuildLogForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BuildLogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            formID = form.save(commit=False)
            formID.author = request.user
            formID.post_id = pk
            formID.save()
            return redirect('build-log-view', formID.pk)
            
    context = { 'form':form,  }

    return render(request, 'blog/buildlog_form.html', context)
```

The url structure setup is post->buildlog(subpost) ie: /post/118/build-log/69/

The form gets successfully submitted but I get the error `NoReverseMatch at /post/118/build-log-form/ Reverse for 'build-log-view' with arguments '(69,)'` What confuses me is the url is still on the post form and not `build log view` but the argument `69` is the correct build log id so it should be working.

url to be redirected to

```
path('post/<int:pk>/build-log/<int:pkz>/', views.BuildLogDisplay, name='build-log-view'),
```

Comment: Can you share the url pattern to which you want to redirect?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem added!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The URL pattern has two parameters: the primary key of the post object, and the primary key of the build log.

You can thus pass this with:

```
return redirect('build-log-view', pk, formID.pk)
```

or with named parameters:

```
return redirect('build-log-view', pk=pk, pkz=formID.pk)
```